# MySQL How To Group by Id that Id contains multiple Ids

Tags: mysql, sql, split

Table qtlsdmx

| Id | pid (Receipt Id) | qrrq (Unix Datetime) | sl (QTY) | je (Total Price Don't * QTY) | spmc (Product Name) | zdcx_ids (Promo Id) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1653839999 | 3 | 127.26 | Product1 | 175,167 |
| 2 | 1 | 1653839999 | 2 | 84.84 | Product2 | 175,167 |
| 3 | 1 | 1653839999 | 1 | 183.42 | Product3 | 167 |
| 4 | 1 | 1653839999 | 1 | 165.74 | Product4 | 167 |
| 5 | 1 | 1653839999 | 1 | 165.74 | Product4 | 167 |

Table zdcxd    (Id = Table qtlsdmx Column zdcx_ids)

| Id (Promo Id) | hdmc (Promo Name) |
| --- | --- |
| 167 | $500 - $40 |
| 175 | $25 VOUCHER |
| 177 | $50 VOUCHER |
| 179 | $75 VOUCHER |

Table qtlsd   (Id = Table qtlsdmx Column pid)

| Id (Receipt Id) | zddm (Shop name) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SHOP01 |
| 2 | SHOP02 |
| 3 | SHOP03 |

I need to analyze some promotion using above table.
The main issue is `zdcx_ids` can contains multiple promotion id. But I need to group it one at a time. I'd tried to create a new column with splitted `zdcx_ids` (SEE REF1 Output). But this method basically duplicate the record and cause Id not unique and QTY, Price etc. incorrect.
May I ask how to possible to code it? If possible please avoid using `IN` and `LIKE "%175%"` method. Because there's over 8mil record in it and loading time is huge.

REF1 Output:

| Id | pid (Receipt Id) | qrrq (Unix Datetime) | sl (QTY) | je (Total Price Don't * QTY) | spmc (Product Name) | zdcx_ids (Promo Id) | splitted_zdcx_ids (Splitted Promo Id) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1653839999 | 3 | 127.26 | Product1 | 175,167 | 175 |
| 1 | 1 | 1653839999 | 3 | 127.26 | Product1 | 175,167 | 167 |
| 2 | 1 | 1653839999 | 2 | 84.84 | Product2 | 175,167 | 175 |
| 2 | 1 | 1653839999 | 2 | 84.84 | Product2 | 175,167 | 167 |
| 3 | 1 | 1653839999 | 1 | 183.42 | Product3 | 167 | 167 |
| 4 | 1 | 1653839999 | 1 | 165.74 | Product4 | 167 | 167 |
| 5 | 1 | 1653839999 | 1 | 165.74 | Product4 | 167 | 167 |

Here are my 3 expected output.

Expected output 1 :

| Id (Promo Id) | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 167 | 5 |
| 175 | 2 |
| 177 | 0 |
| 179 | 0 |

Expected output 2 :

| Id (Promo Id) | Price (Only Sum zdcx_ids if exist) | <--- RESULT FORMULA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 167 | $727 | 127.26 + 84.84 + 183.42 + 165.7 + 165.74 |
| 175 | $212.1 | 127.26 + 84.84 |
| 177 | $0 |  |
| 179 | $0 |  |

Expected output 3 :

| Id (Promo Id) | Price (If zdcx_ids exist Id, Sum je with same pid) | <--- RESULT FORMULA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 167 | $727 | 127.26 + 84.84 + 183.42 + 165.7 + 165.74 |
| 175 | $727 | 127.26 + 84.84 + 183.42 + 165.7 + 165.74 |
| 177 | $0 |  |
| 179 | $0 |  |

My progress for solution 1:

```
SET @tDate := '2022-05-29';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qtlsdmx
        WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(qrrq) >= @tDate AND FROM_UNIXTIME(qrrq) < DATE_ADD(@tDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                and zdcx_ids like '%175%' group by pid 
) a ;
```

My progress for solution 2:

```
select sum(je) 
        from qtlsdmx 
    where FROM_UNIXTIME(qrrq) >= @tDate and FROM_UNIXTIME(qrrq) < DATE_ADD(@tDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                and pid in (select pid from qtlsdmx where zdcx_ids like '%175%');
```

My progress for solution 3:

```
SET @tDate := '2022-05-29';  
SELECT SUM(je) AS TOTALPRICE
FROM qtlsdmx 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(qrrq) >= @tDate AND FROM_UNIXTIME(qrrq) < DATE_ADD(@tDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
and pid in (select pid from qtlsdmx where zdcx_ids like '%175%');
```

Comment: About the `zdck_ids`  column, now you're showing some have `175,167` value but will there be other rows where it's more than just 2 value separated by comma? Perhaps `175,167,169,179 ...` and so on?

Comment: And please post what you've attempted so far.

Comment: @FanoFN Yes it can be more than just 2 value separated by comma. And this can also be duplicate for example 175,175,175 which use $25 VOUCHER 3 times

Comment: @FanoFN I added some code that I attempted to this post

Comment: What is the maximum value separated by comma? I'm thinking that you can possibly do this with `UNION ALL` as the base query but it might not be ideal if the comma separated value is a lot. Maybe with prepared statement.

Comment: @FanoFN Most likely won’t more than 5 but there’s few special case that contains more than 10

Comment: I guess we can try with `UNION ALL` as possible solution but it might not be that easy on older MySQL version. What is your MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check.

Comment: @FanoFN It's running on 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` and `UNION ALL` to make comma separated values generated by each of their own row. So, we are going to turn this row:

| Id | pid | qrrq | sl | je | spmc | zdcx_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1653839999 | 3 | 127.26 | Product1 | 175,167 |

to:

| Id | pid | qrrq | sl | je | spmc | zdcx_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1653839999 | 3 | 127.26 | Product1 | 175 |
| 1 | 1 | 1653839999 | 3 | 127.26 | Product1 | 167 |

With this query, we'll get the first in comma separated value of `zdcx_ids`:

```
SELECT Id, pid, qrrq, sl, je, spmc, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(zdcx_ids,',',1),',',-1) 
FROM qtlsdmx;
```

The reason why we're doing `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` twice it to cater for the next value after the comma. There's another part we need to add in to the query, which is the count of comma separated value. I think I've seen a different method somewhere but the one on top of my head is subtraction of string length between the original value and the value where the comma is being removed and then add 1:

```
WHERE LENGTH(zdcx_ids)-LENGTH(REPLACE(zdcx_ids,',','')) +1 >= 1
```

The result of the length subtraction on `zdcx_ids=175,167` will return `1` since there's only 1 comma so the count is not correct. Obviously `175,167` should have two value count which is why we add `+1` at the end of the subtraction result. The `>= 1` is just telling the query to return result if the count value is equal or more than the checked value. We'll add this into the query:

```
SELECT Id, pid, qrrq, sl, je, spmc, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(zdcx_ids,',',1),',',-1) 
FROM qtlsdmx
WHERE LENGTH(zdcx_ids)-LENGTH(REPLACE(zdcx_ids,',','')) +1 >= 1
```

Now we'll add the remaining original condition that you've placed and do `UNION ALL` with the same query structure but with different count or numbering sequence. There are two parts we need to change for the second query:

```
SET @tDate := '2022-05-29';

SELECT Id, pid, qrrq, sl, je, spmc, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(zdcx_ids,',',1),',',-1) 
 FROM qtlsdmx
 WHERE LENGTH(zdcx_ids)-LENGTH(REPLACE(zdcx_ids,',','')) +1 >= 1
  /*adding the rest of your condition*/
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(qrrq) >= @tDate 
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(qrrq) < DATE_ADD(@tDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, pid, qrrq, sl, je, spmc, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(zdcx_ids,',',2),',',-1) 
 FROM qtlsdmx
 WHERE LENGTH(zdcx_ids)-LENGTH(REPLACE(zdcx_ids,',','')) +1 >= 2
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(qrrq) >= @tDate 
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(qrrq) < DATE_ADD(@tDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Notice the changes in the second query at the first `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` and the value count. Depending on your data, you might have to repeat the same query for 10 times with incremental value on those two parts. You probably can consider using `PREPARED STATEMENT` for this. I'll get to that later.

Once the `UNION ALL` queries done, you can make it as subquery, `LEFT JOIN` and do the calculation:

For expected output 1:

```
SELECT t1.Id, COUNT(t2.Id) 
  FROM zdcxd AS t1  
 LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT Id, pid, qrrq, sl, je, spmc, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(zdcx_ids,',',1),',',-1) AS val /*assigning alias*/
 FROM qtlsdmx
 WHERE LENGTH(zdcx_ids)-LENGTH(REPLACE(zdcx_ids,',','')) +1 >= 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, pid, qrrq, sl, je, spmc, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(zdcx_ids,',',2),',',-1) 
 FROM qtlsdmx
 WHERE LENGTH(zdcx_ids)-LENGTH(REPLACE(zdcx_ids,',','')) +1 >= 2) AS t2
ON t1.Id=t2.val 
GROUP BY t1.Id;
```

For expected output 2, you need to just change `COUNT(t2.Id)` to `SUM(je)`:

```
SELECT t1.Id, SUM(je)
  FROM zdcxd AS t1  
 LEFT JOIN 
...
```

As for expected output 3, I'm still trying to understand how to make that work so I haven't got any suggestion on that yet. I'll update this post if I've figured it out somehow but hopefully you manage to figure it out yourself too.

Now, since this `UNION ALL` query depend on how many comma separated value, it will definitely be a long query. So I suggest using MySQL [prepare statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html#:%7E:text=The%20PREPARE%20statement%20prepares%20a,names%20are%20not%20case%2Dsensitive.) to generate the query with some customized sequence numbering.

Here's a fiddle of the full prepare statement queries

1. [Fiddle 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0507ef3050adcbd6ffd8d544f62800a0).
2. [Fiddle 2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iV84ahE9HsNhjMYUCusjK4/6) - in case the first fiddle is not working.